# Flutter - Navigator.pop() - rebuild origin screen with setState()

Tags: flutter

How can I rebuild with my "HomeScreen" with setState after I've manipulated some displayed data (in HomeScreen) in a SecondScreen? I'm using Navigator.pop() but it isn't showing the changes.

SecondScreen:

```
      onPressed: () {
        setState(
          () {
            holidays[widget.index].start = test;
          },
        );
        Navigator.pop(
          context,
        );
      },
```

On my homescreen I have a list of "holidays". In the Holiday class I have a button....

```
                   GestureDetector(
                         onTap: () async {
                              await Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => EditScreen(
                                      start: start, end: end, index: index),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
```

Comment: Could you share your code to better understand what your problem is?

Comment: You can either use `Navigator.pop(value);` or callback.

Comment: Can you elaborate on those two methods? and provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling `setState()` after `Navigator.push()` ?

Comment: Navigator.push() is in a the Holiday class so I'm unable to do that.

Comment: Oh, yes.. what about using ValueNotifier and adding listener to it?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I had to create a callback function in my main file which is basically just `setState()`, pass the function when creating an instance of `Holiday`, and then run the callback function after `await Navigator.push()`

Callback function:

```
  void rebuild() {
    print("test");
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Navigator.push() in my Holiday class

```
                    onTap: () async {
                      await Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => EditScreen(
                              start: start,
                              end: end,
                              index: index,
                              ),
                        ),
                      );
                      rebuild!();
                    },
```